# How to deal with a conflict between packages that involve typescript?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, meteor

I was following this tutorial for creating a whatsapp clone on meteor: https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/meteor/chats-mutations

and was right at the bottom of section 8. I ran the

```
$meteor reset command
```

as instructed however, when I then ran the

```
$ npm run start
```

in the terminal, I got the following error:

```
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Errors prevented startup:                  

   While building the application:
   error: Could not resolve meteor.mainModule "server/main.js" in package.json
   (os)
   error: Could not resolve meteor.mainModule "client/main.js" in package.json
   (web.browser)
   error: Could not resolve meteor.mainModule "client/main.js" in package.json
   (web.browser.legacy)
   error: Could not resolve meteor.mainModule "client/main.js" in package.json
   (web.cordova)

   While determining active plugins:
   error: conflict: two packages included in the app (barbatus:typescript and
   typescript) are both trying to handle *.ts
   error: conflict: two packages included in the app (barbatus:typescript and
   typescript) are both trying to handle *.tsx

   While loading plugin `compileFonts` from package `mys:fonts`:
   <anonymous>: Unexpected end of JSON input
   at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
   at getConfig (packages/compileFonts/plugin.js:70:23)
   at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.compileFonts.plugin.js
   (packages/compileFonts/plugin.js:18:25)
   at fileEvaluate
   (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:141:1)
   at require
   (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:75:1)
   at <runJavaScript-49>:17308:1
   at <runJavaScript-49>:17314:3


   While determining active plugins:
   error: conflict: two packages included in the app (barbatus:typescript and
   typescript) are both trying to handle *.ts
   error: conflict: two packages included in the app (barbatus:typescript and
   typescript) are both trying to handle *.tsx

   While determining active plugins:
   error: conflict: two packages included in the app (barbatus:typescript and
   typescript) are both trying to handle *.ts
   error: conflict: two packages included in the app (barbatus:typescript and
   typescript) are both trying to handle *.tsx

   While determining active plugins:
   error: conflict: two packages included in the app (barbatus:typescript and
   typescript) are both trying to handle *.ts
   error: conflict: two packages included in the app (barbatus:typescript and
   typescript) are both trying to handle *.tsx

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
=> Started MongoDB.
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

If it helps, I am doing this project in Visual Studio Code

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Meteor has now official Typescript support, you can safely drop `barbartus:typescript` however it's a peer dependency in a package of the tutorial's repo (it has not been updated in 3 years).

Remove the `angular2-compilers` from  `.meteor/packages` and replace it with the `angular-compilers` ([link](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/angular-compilers)) which should make it work.